# transferring data from my database to my friends database

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, data-migration

Just created a database in my own MySQL server. Now I want to transfer the data from my MySQL server to one of my friend's MySQL server.

Any idea how this can be done?

Also, how would I do this if I use oracle server?

Comment: It is a good idea to check right answers from time to time...

Answer (score 3):

If you have an access to his database - you can create [dblink](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm)

Otherwise you have to [export a dump](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+) and send it to your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to copy full databases (as well as just selected tables) between servers before and a SQL dump can be cumbersome if you have a lot of data. If you have access to both servers you might consider an application called "Navicat". It is a MySQL GUI interface to manage databases.

You can have multiple databases on separate servers open at the same time, and can even "drag and drop" tables between databases and databases between servers.